# Cannot Get Broadcom bcm43142 Wifi Adapter to Work on Toshiba Satellite (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kernel, broadcom

I just removed the Windows partition on my Toshiba Satellite C55, but when I did so I lost the functionality of my **Broadcom bcm43142 wifi adapter**.  It is odd because the OS seems to recognize that the driver exists, yet there is no way actually turn it on.  Pictures below:

[image: "Software & Updates" shows that a proprietary driver is in use]

[image: "Settings" does not recognize that there is a driver]

I am at my wits end here.  I have done everything in my power to try to fix this issue.  I have taken the following steps:

**FIRST)**
I attempted to reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source.  I ran the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

No luck.

**SECOND)**
I tried to purge and reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source at root level.  I ran the following commands:

```
sudo -i
apt update
apt upgrade
apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
reboot

sudo -i
apt update
apt-get install build-essential    # Just to make sure it was installed
update-pciids
apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
reboot
```

No luck.

**THIRD)**
I booted into Toshiba's BIOS and ensured that Secure Boot was disabled.  It is listed as disabled.

Obviously, no luck.

**FOURTH)**
I ignored the above and disabled Secure Boot in shim-signed anyway.  I took the following steps:

```
sudo mokutil --disable-validation
```

I then followed the prompts in MOK management (selected "Change Secure Boot State," entered my password, and selected YES to disable secure boot) and changed the secure boot state successfully.

No luck.

## Wrapping Up

Seriously, what more can I do here?  Please let me know if I can give you any terminal outputs.  I know enough in the bash to try things for you, but unfortunately not necessarily enough to proactively provide that info for you.  Thank you from the bottom of my heart for anyone who can help here!

-Ryan

Comment: Is there anthing in this thread which guides you? https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: Are there any bcmwl errors in the kernel log?

Comment: @dragosht, are you asking for the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`?  If so I get the following: `07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [11ad:6655]
 Kernel driver in use: wl
 Kernel modules: wl
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
3: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no`

Comment: Nope. I'm talking about dmesg output.

Comment: @dragosht the dmesg output is incredibly long, is there a relevant portion or should I post it for you somewhere?  I appreciate your help here!

Comment: `dmesg | grep wl`

Comment: @dragosht, thank you for that!  Output is as follows: `[   16.912195] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   16.912198] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   16.946424] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4365 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
[   18.021155] wl 0000:07:00.0 wlp7s0: renamed from wlan0`

Comment: Ok, so there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the driver ...

Answer (score 1):

The broadcom open source driver appears to be unsigned and is thus blocked by the UEFI secure boot process. Try disable secure boot in the bios and try again.